# Set default value for jQuery slider and override when needed

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Background:** I currently have a **working** jQuery slider on my website inside my .js file

```
$( "#slider-range-min" ).slider({
      range: "min",
      value: 100,
      min: 1,
      max: 100,
    });
```

I need to be able to override the "Value" from 100 to some other value sometimes. So I tried this:

```
$( "#slider-range-min" ).slider({
      range: "min",
      value: _Slider_Value,
      min: 1,
      max: 100,
    });
```

and defined this on my html page

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    var _Slider_Value = 50;
</script>
```

which also works! **Except** then on all the other pages I get a javascript error stating "_Slider_Value is not defined". I'd rather not have to copy & paste the value onto all my pages if I can avoid it... doesnt seem like a "good" way to do it?

**Question:** is there a better way to do this - so I can have a default value for my slider, but occasionally override it when required?

**Edit:** Another way of saying it: how do I make my slider default to "100" unless I tell it otherwise in my html page?

Comment: define that in a js file which you are including in every page

Comment: thanks Satya - that worked - post it as an answer so I can accept it for you

Comment: posted :) glad that I could help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define that in a js file which you are including in every page

Answer (score 2):

place a `span` in your html where you have slider in a `div` container here is (`id="slider-range-min"`)

```
<span class="min">100</span>
```

read this value in your slider function

```
$( "#slider-range-min" ).slider({
      range: "min",
      value: $(this).find('.min').text();,
      min: 1,
      max: 100,
    });
```

wherever u need the value to be update on the page change the span value dynamically if need else it will take the default value eg. 100 here.

Comment: thanks Murtaza - but that only works when I have a slider on my page - i have some pages without sliders (but still loading the slider function in my generic minified js file

Comment: I think @Satya has explained you the answer, so u can you that technique.. :)

Answer (score 2):

if you are trying to minimize variables you can always check

```
if (_Slider_Value != undefined) {
    //your code here
}
```

or

```
(_Slider_Value != undefined) ? _Slider_Value : 100;
```

so your final code can be

```
$( "#slider-range-min" ).slider({
  range: "min",
  value: (_Slider_Value != undefined) ? _Slider_Value : 100,
  min: 1,
  max: 100,
});
```

that will default to 100 if there is no value in _Slider_Value

Answer (score 1):

You can override options of the slider with this string. 
              $('#slider-range-min').slider({value: 50});

Answer (score 1):

Declare your variable globally to access it anywhere in web page. here is the [tutorial link](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp).

Try to declare variable without var key word to make it global

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    _Slider_Value = 50;
</script>
```

if this is not working try binding the variable to window object

```
var myValue;
function setValue()
{
    myValue = "test";
}

function getValue()
{
    alert(window.myValue); // yup, it's "test"
}
```

here is the complete [explanation](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/global_variable), from which i have given example.

hope it works (not practically tried)